# Selecting NULL value from the database

Tags: database, select

I have a database with columns that are allowed to be NULL.

Whenever I run a query against this database using `$wpdb->get_results` the columns that are NULL are always returned with an actual value; the number zero.

In my database NULL and zero actually have totally different meanings and I would like to be able to get the correct values from the database without Wordpress translating the returned value.

How can I select from the database so that NULL values are maintained?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no specific issue with retrieving null values from the database. They will come back as the PHP NULL value.

WordPress uses either the function `mysqli_fetch_object` or `mysql_fetch_object` to retrieve results from the database.

https://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php
https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php

According to those respective pages:

> Note: This function sets NULL fields to the PHP NULL value.

Are you using `is_null()` to check for the value? Or are you comparing the result to the NULL constant using the identity check (`===`)?

Comment: When I'm testing today the NULL values are retrieved just fine and the empty() check on the variables now behave correctly.
I don't know what I did last night for it not to work, but it seems to have resolved itself.
As it works now I blame working late at night :)

Comment: Well.. Be careful with `empty()`. A int of zero is empty. You need to explicitly check for NULL if it's going to be different than zero.